# I'm unable to install IJulia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

ijulia installation is stuck at 100% 
I'm beginner need help.:

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.4.1 (2020-04-14)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
    Cloning default registries into `c:\Users\xxxx\.julia`
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
    Fetching: [========================================>]  100.0 %
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time to install packages for the first time (e.g. 4mins machine with good internet) - you need just wait.

Sometimes this also might happen when you loose internet connection during the install or it is unstable. In that case you can just press Ctrl+C and try again. After pressing Ctrl+C on rare occasions something might be partially installed - in that case you might end up removing the `c:\Users\xxxx\.julia` folder. Good luck!